# finding similar strings in two columns

Tags: r, string

I want to count how many of strings in each row from first column is similar to the string2.

```
df1<- structure(list(string1 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("gdyijq,udyhfs,gqdtr", "hdydg", "hishsgd,gugddf", 
"ydis"), class = "factor")), .Names = "string1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

df2<- structure(list(string2 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
"gqdtr", "hishsgd,gugddf", "ydis"), class = "factor")), .Names = "string2", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

I tried to bind these two to become `dfM`with no sucess

```
dfM <- cbind(df1,df2)
```

df1 looks like 
                  string1
    1      hishsgd,gugddf
    2               hdydg
    3                ydis
    4 gdyijq,udyhfs,gqdtr
    5 gdyijq,udyhfs,gqdtr
    6 gdyijq,udyhfs,gqdtr
    7 gdyijq,udyhfs,gqdtr

and df2, looks like

```
        string2
1 hishsgd,gugddf
2              0
3           ydis
4          gqdtr
```

I want to have it like this

```
dfN<- structure(list(string1 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("gdyijq,udyhfs,gqdtr", "hdydg", "hishsgd,gugddf", 
"ydis"), class = "factor"), string2 = structure(c(4L, 2L, 5L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "0", "gqdtr", "hishsgd,gugddf", 
"ydis"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("string1", "string2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))


################## second part ###############
```

and the second part is

```
 dfN<- structure(list(string1 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("gdyijq,udyhfs,gqdtr", 
    "hdydg", "hishsgd,gugddf", "ydis"), class = "factor"), string2 = structure(c(3L, 
    1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "gqdtr", "hishsgd,gugddf", "ydis"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("string1", "string2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -4L))
```

for example in the first row

```
string1            string2
hishsgd,gugddf    hishsgd,gugddf
```

so it should be 2

in the second row

```
string1            string2
hdydg                 0
```

they are not similar which should be 0 then

and so on, the expected output is like below

```
renew<- structure(list(string1 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("gdyijq,udyhfs,gqdtr", 
"hdydg", "hishsgd,gugddf", "ydis"), class = "factor"), string2 = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "gqdtr", "hishsgd,gugddf", "ydis"
), class = "factor"), similar = c(2L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("string1", 
"string2", "similar"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `strsplit` to split the strings in each columns, get the common elements on each `list` element with `intersect` and `Map` and find the `length` with `lengths`

```
lst <- lapply(dfN, function(x) strsplit(as.character(x), ","))
renew1 <- transform(dfN, similar = lengths(Map(intersect, lst[[1]], lst[[2]])))
identical(renew, renew1)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @nik I am not sure what you are after, but try `library(rowr);cbind.fill(df1, df2)`

Comment: `library(rowr);cbind.fill(df1, df2)`fills the empty places by other strings randomly. I showed an example above, what I want as output. by the way I accepted and liked your answer

Comment: @nik You can use `fill` argument i.e. `cbind.fill(df1, df2, fill = NA)`

Comment: Shouldn't we go upstream and check why df2 has fewer rows than df1, instead of having NA filled rows? Otherwise how can we be so sure that row n of df1 is to be matched with row n of df2..  @akrun -- thanks for introducing me  to rowr

Comment: @R.S. not really because they come from two different sources. so I do know why the have different lengths and that is correct for me.

Comment: @akrun I have a silly question, look how I am doing it, is there a way that I don't turn around to get the dfN and manipulate it on my out itself ? this is what I do `dfN <- out[,5:6]` then `lst <- lapply(dfN, function(x) strsplit(as.character(x), ","))` then `renew1 <- transform(dfN, similar = lengths(Map(intersect, lst[[1]], lst[[2]])))` then `out2 <- cbind(out,renew1$similar)`

Comment: @nik YOu may try it on the `data.table` by specifying the `.SDcols` as 5:6, loop through the column, do the split and create the 'similar'

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `%in%` to do the matching

```
dfN<- structure(list(string1 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("gdyijq,udyhfs,gqdtr", 
    "hdydg", "hishsgd,gugddf", "ydis"), class = "factor"), string2 = structure(c(3L, 
    1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "gqdtr", "hishsgd,gugddf", "ydis"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("string1", "string2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -4L))
renew<- structure(list(string1 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("gdyijq,udyhfs,gqdtr", 
"hdydg", "hishsgd,gugddf", "ydis"), class = "factor"), string2 = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "gqdtr", "hishsgd,gugddf", "ydis"
), class = "factor"), similar = c(2L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("string1", 
"string2", "similar"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

dfN
renew

# use strsplit to break up the cell values
col1<- strsplit(as.character(dfN$string1),",")
col2<- strsplit(as.character(dfN$string2),",")

#use %in% to find match
res<- mapply(FUN="%in%", col1, col2)

#sum up the TRUE values
res2<- lapply(res,sum)

# merge the result
resultDF<- data.frame(dfN, newcol= unlist(res2))

#test
resultDF==  renew  #data.frame(dfN, newcol= 1:4  )
```